# How to set ordering of categories in Pandas stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make a Pandas bar plot with custom-ordered categories (elements shown with different colors). Here's my code, where I expect the ordering of the categories from bottom to top to follow "catorder":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"series":["ser1","ser1","ser1", "ser2", "ser2","ser2"], 
                    "cate":["aatu","boiler","heat pump","aatu","boiler","heat pump"],
                    "val": [6,15,24,7,15, 21] })


ac2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, values = "val", index = "series", columns = "cate")

catorder= ["heat pump","aatu","boiler"]
ac2.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(ac2.columns.values, 
                                 ordered=True, 
                                 categories=catorder)
ac2.sort_index(axis = 1)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3.5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ac2.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax = ax1)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. Categories are still in alphabetical order. Any ideas how to accomplish this common task?

Comment: `ac2 = ac2.sort_index(axis=1)` or `ac2.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the data before plotting:

```
ac2.sort_index(axis=1).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax = ax1)
```

Output:

[image]